# Vue multiple options per loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Trying to display multiple options in Vue2 for loop of a select.

Given an object with the structure;

```
sorting = {
    name: [
        'asc',
        'desc'
    ],
    price: [
        'cheapest',
        'expensive'
    ]
}
```

How to format the loop to get the output of;

```
<select>
    <option value="name:asc">name asc</option>
    <option value="name:desc">name desc</option>
    <option value="price:cheapest">name cheapest</option>
    <option value="price:expensive">name expensive</option>
</select>
```

Can't work out the way to show the second option;

```
<select id="sortBy" class="form-control pr-3" v-model="sortBy">
    <option
        v-for="(options, sort) in sorting" :key="`${sort}`"
        v-bind:value="`${sort}:${options[0]}`"
    >
        {{ sort }} {{ options[0] }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add what `options` is? and also what is `sorting` you are looping through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `sorting` data contains nested arrays: you need to iterate through each keys (you've done done), and the also iterate through the array in each key to generate the options.

My suggestion is that instead of trying to do that in the template, which can be verbose and less readable... you can abstract that into a computed property that handles the option generation for you.

The trick here is simply using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (which returns a `key` and `value` tuple) and then iterating through the value to return the `key:arrayValue` combination. Use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to flatten the returned array:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    sorting: {
      name: [
        'asc',
        'desc'
      ],
      price: [
        'cheapest',
        'expensive'
      ]
    },
    sortBy: '',
  },
  computed: {
    options() {
      return Object.entries(this.sorting).flatMap(([key, optionsByKey]) => {
        return optionsByKey.map(v => `${key}:${v}`);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select id="sortBy" class="form-control pr-3" v-model="sortBy">
    <option v-for="(option, i) in options" :key="i" :value="option">
      {{ option.replace(':', ' ') }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br /><br />
  Selected value: {{ sortBy }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two `option` loops.

```js
<select id="sortBy" class="form-control pr-3" v-model="sortBy">
    <option
        v-for="n in options.name" :key="`name:${n}`"
        :value="`name:${n}`"
    >
        name {{ n }}
    </option>
    <option
        v-for="p in options.price" :key="`price:${p}`"
        :value="`price:${p}`"
    >
        price {{ p }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: the sortable object can be passed in, so can have X attributes.